# How to access data from WordPress database using JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json, database, wordpress

I am new in android and I am developing an application in which I have to use a built in database of WordPress.

I have to get all the data stored in this database to be utilized in my android application. I want to access all data through JSON. Data in that database contains magazines. Now I am confused that how can I access this data indeed. Whether I have to access whole magazine and just display in my app or there is some other criteria.

Comment: Use [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin in WordPress...

Comment: Could you send me the example...actually I didn't work on it before

Comment: Install `JSON API` plugin into WordPress and go to JSON API page in wordpress admin...There you will find links to get json data<, With that links you can get json data in your android device...

Comment: See [This Link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)..This is documentation of that plugin...

Comment: I don't have access to the WordPress....I just have database with me in downloaded form

Comment: Than simply set up WordPress in your local and try to get achieve your data...Coz WordPress DB Structure is little complex so you cant get data with simple SQL query.....

Comment: Locally I have Database with me and here is the link to that database https://drive.google.com/#my-drive , but I don't know how I can utilize it in my android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on how 'magazine' is stored in your wordpress database. (you will have to ask the creator of 'magazine' to get the answer).

If it is a Custom Post Type, you can use the JSON API that Akshay has mentioned. You will have to learn how to use it...but once you do it will be simple.

If it is custom managed by the author, you will have to ask the author if they have already built an API that you can use that returns JSON. If they have, then you can access it with their API.

If not, you will have to write custom code that retrieves the data from the database and provides it to your android app in a JSON format. You may be able to do this in any language pending server availability and connectivity.